# Angular2+ Kendo Grid - Is there a way to combine "Select All" with Virtual scrolling

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

Basically what I need to do is have the select all checkbox also select all of the virtual rows that haven't been "scrolled to" yet. Is something like that possible?

Here's a stackblitz link to one of the examples from [Telerik's demos](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/selection/#toc-select-all-feature) I've been playing around with:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2e4uik

Right now clicking the select all only selects the first 10 rows since that's what the Grid's "pagesize is set to..